# Using Google Pub/Sub Java client library without adding the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable for authentication

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Pub/Sub is really easy to use from my local work station. I set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path to my .json authentication object.

But what if you need to interact with multiple different Pub/Sub projects? This seems like an odd way to do authentication. Shouldn't there be a way to pass the .json object in from the Java code?

How can I use the client libraries without setting the system's environment variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can grant access for PubSub in different project using single Service Account and set it as env variable. See [PubSub Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A service account JSON key file allows to identify a service account on GCP. This service account is the equivalent of a user account but for the app (without user, only machine).

Thereby, if your app need to interact with several topic from different projects, you simply have to grant the service account email with the correct role on each topics/projects.

Another important thing. The service account key file are useful for **app outside GCP**. Else it's bad. Let me explain this. The service account key file is a secret file that you have to keep and store securely. And a file, it's easy to copy it, to send it by email and even to commit it into public git repository... In addition, it's recommended to rotate this key at least every 90 days for security reasons.

So, for all these reasons and the difficulty in security that represent the service account key files, I don't recommend you to use them.

- With your local environment, use your user account (simply use the gcloud SDK and perform a `gcloud auth application-default auth`). Your aren't a machine (I hope!!)
- With GCP component, use the component "identity" (load a service account when you deploy a service, create a VM,..., and grant the correct role on this service account without generating JSON key
- With external app (other cloud provider, on premise, Apigee, CI/CD pipeline,...), generate a JSON file on your service account, you can't avoid them in this case.

Comment: I think I understand. In my situation the Pub/Sub project isn't mine. I'm integrating a few systems, and one sends data with Pub/Sub, so I need to receive from it. Is there a .jar somewhere for the client library? (google-cloud-pubsub) Or do I need to build a whole project or generate my own library jar?

Comment: You have libraries for all products and in several languages, [pubsub included](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java). You don't need to interact with your projects, but only with the project where you are authorized.